# Let the ellipse size changes

Tags: if-statement, p5.js, ellipse, milliseconds

I am writing a code that can interact with the mouse movement. And now

```
let myY = 0;
let shape;

function setup() { 
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  shape = millis();
} 

function draw() { 
  background(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you meant so I made these two. You don't have to use millis() since draw runs every frame and frameCount can be divided by 60 to get seconds (if the frame rate is set to 60 which is the default), basically frameCount is simpler.

```
let myY = 0;
let myX = 0;

let mX = 0;
let mY = 0;
function setup() { 
  createCanvas(400, 400);
} 

function draw() { 
  background(0);
  
  
  myX = lerp(myX, mouseX, 0.05);
  myY = lerp(myY, mouseY, 0.05);
  fill(random(255),random(255),random(255));
  ellipse(myX, myY,40,10);
  
  myX = lerp(myX, mouseX, 0.05);
  myY = lerp(myY, mouseY, 0.05);
  ellipse(myX, myY,10,40);
  
  


  fill(255, 192);
  stroke(0, 255);
  strokeWeight(2);
  let spacing = 10;
  if(frameCount % 60 == 0){
    mX = mouseX;
    mY = mouseY;
  }
  for (let i = spacing; i < width; i += spacing) {
    for (let j = spacing/2; j < height; j += spacing) {
      let di = dist(mX, mY, i, j);
      ellipse(i, j, di * 0.2);
      }
    }
  
}
```

.

```
let myY = 0;
let myX = 0;
function setup() { 
  createCanvas(400, 400);
} 

function draw() { 
  background(0);
  
  
  myX = lerp(myX, mouseX, 0.05);
  myY = lerp(myY, mouseY, 0.05);
  fill(random(255),random(255),random(255));
  ellipse(myX, myY,40,10);
  
  myX = lerp(myX, mouseX, 0.05);
  myY = lerp(myY, mouseY, 0.05);
  ellipse(myX, myY,10,40);
  
  


  fill(255, 192);
  stroke(0, 255);
  strokeWeight(2);
  let spacing = 10;
  for (let i = spacing; i < width; i += spacing) {
    for (let j = spacing/2; j < height; j += spacing) {
      let di = dist(mouseX, mouseY, i, j);
      ellipse(i, j, di * map(cos(frameCount / 20),0,1,0,0.2));
      }
    }
    
}
```